# Find a linear relation for $a_n=3^n-2^n+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence with general term $a_n=3^n-2^n+1$. Write a first order constant coefficient linear(not necessarily homogeneous) relation together with a sufficient number of initial terms to describe.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Perhaps you'll find it easier to think about $b_n=a_n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility:
As $1,2,3$ are roots of the polynomial
$$(X-1)(X-2)(X-3) =X^3-6X^2+11X-6,$$
we conclude that the sequences $a_n=1^n$, $a_n=2^n$, and $a_n=3^n$ all follow the recursion 
$$\tag1a_n=6a_{n-1}-11a_{n-2}+6a_{n-3}.$$
So does any linear combination of these, in particular, so does $a_n=3^n-2^n+1$.
Before $(1)$ can apply, we need to give our sequence a start of three terms, i.e., $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$, $a_2=6$.